# SQL Server 2016 Compare values from multiple columns in multiple rows in single table

Tags: sql-server, compare, multiple-columns, rows

```
USE dev_db 
GO 

CREATE TABLE T1_VALS 
(
    [SITE_ID] [int] NULL, 
    [LATITUDE] [numeric](10, 6) NULL, 
    [UNIQUE_ID] [int] NULL, 
    [COLLECT_RANK] [int] NULL, 
    [CREATED_RANK] [int] NULL, 
    [UNIQUE_ID_RANK] [int] NULL, 
    [UPDATE_FLAG] [int] NULL 
)    
GO

INSERT INTO T1_VALS 
    (SITE_ID,LATITUDE,UNIQUE_ID,COLLECT_RANK,CREATED_RANK,UNIQUEID_RANK)    
VALUES
    (207442,40.900470,59664,1,1,1) 
    (207442,40.900280,61320,1,1,2) 
    (204314,40.245220,48685,1,2,2) 
    (204314,40.245910,59977,1,1,1) 
    (202416,39.449530,9295,1,1,2) 
    (202416,39.449680,62264,1,1,1)
```

I generated the `COLLECT_RANK` and `CREATED_RANK` columns from two date columns (not shown here) and the `UNIQUEID_RANK` column from the `UNIQUE_ID` which is used here.

I used a `SELECT OVER` clause with ranking function to generate these columns. A `_RANK` value of 1 means the latest date or greatest `UNIQUE_ID` value. I thought my solution would be pretty straight forward using these rank values via array and cursor processing but I seem to have painted myself into a corner.

My problem: I need to choose `LONGITUDE` value and its `UNIQUE_ID` based upon the following business rules and set the update value, (1), for that record in its `UPDATE_FLAG` column.

Select the record w/most recent Collection Date (i.e. RANK value = 1) for a given SITE_ID. If multiple records exist w/same Collection Date (i.e. same RANK value), select the record w/most recent Created Date (RANK value =1) for a given SITE_ID. If multiple records exist w/same Created Date, select the record w/highest Unique ID for a given SITE_ID (i.e. RANK value = 1).

Your suggestions would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `top` and `order by`:

```
select top 1 t1.*
from t1_vals
order by collect_rank asc, create_rank, unique_id desc;
```

If you want this for sites, which might be what your question is asking, then use `row_number()`:

```
select t1.*
from (select t1.*,
             row_number() over (partition by site_id order by collect_rank asc, create_rank, unique_id desc) as seqnum
      from t1_vals
     ) t1
where seqnum = 1;
```